# Windows 10 drivers for Macbook's FaceTime HD Camera won't allow anything other than 720p

Tags: windows-10, drivers, macbook, boot-camp, webcam

I'm not sure if I should be asking this here or over in *Ask Different*, but given that Windows 10 is the OS I'm working in, here's where I am...

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro running Windows 10 Pro via BootCamp.  The laptop has a 720p camera called "FaceTime HD Camera" which works fine with the Windows 10 Camera app.  It works fine with most webcam enabled sites in Chrome, FireFox and Edge, it works fine with ManyCam.  But it only works when set to 720p.

If I change the resolution to 640x480, 640x320 or lower, the image just goes black, or in Windows 10 Camera App's case - it also shows a 0x8... error code.

I discovered this because I have to use Adobe Connect for a Uni assignment and I cannot get the camera working in that at all.  Apparently that application supports up to 640x480@20FPS and whilst it detects the FaceTime HD Camera, there is no image when you start the webcam.

Using ManyCam, if you change the video format from 720p to 480p or lower, the camera stops working, change it back and it works fine.

Use a different webcam (eg. Logitech C920 Pro) in 480p or lower with any of the applications or websites and the image is fine.

So whilst using an external camera is a workaround, it would be great to actually have a fix for the issue.

Any ideas?